# How to properly execute a CRON job without CPanel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I've tried to use multiple variations but failed to run properly CRON job since I moved to another hosting.

Before I've just called an http link like so on the pic below:

[image]

Filename `/cron/synchronize.php` contains following code:

`<?php shell_exec('php /var/www/domain.com/artisan domaincom:cron argument1 argument2 --option1');?>`

I can't find where does the real crontab file is stored, so I could copy the real code...

Now once I'm on new hosting, via terminal I moved to `/var/spool/cron` and then I typed in command line `crontab -e` where I placed my code:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/
0 8,12,14,16,19,23 * * * php /var/www/domain.com/cron/synchronize.php
```

And that code is not working, anyone who can tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Seems redundant to use php to execute a shell command to execute a second php script. Why not just use `php /var/www/domain.com/artisan domaincom:cron argument1 argument2 --option1` in crontab?

Comment: i tried that also, but seems not working either, I do not know where does the crontab stores that file, or where I should save it. Maybe I should store it and call it or run it somehow ? thank you for your reply

Comment: You shpuld be getting emails if your cron job is failing or generating any output. Did you put the SHELL and HOME line in the crontab? I have never seen that before.

Comment: @JasonK - that's what was described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps (pls reffer to OUTPUT section)

Comment: Don't you have a visual interface to deal with cron jobs in your new hosting? Sometimes cron jobs are managed through different users (meaning Linux-Unix type of users) so you have to edit the cron tab through that specific user.

Comment: That's good to know. I've never saw that before.

Comment: @MarkSkayff - I'm using a DigitalOcean VPS hosting, so there is no User Interface (visual interface or any kind of control panel for managing the crons like it was in previous hosting provider on the pic)

Comment: one thing I would test is to setup a cronjob echo "test cron" >>SomeFile to test that it's running.

Comment: That's a good suggestion from Jason above. So you can mini test the cron ... maybe you can make it run every minute and check the file with "cat", "tail" or other Linux command and see if it's working.

Comment: Guys, thank you for help, testing it with writing to a file was good solution to check that is working, so everything was ok, I will accept an answer if @HPierce would give me an answer like it was in his comment.

Comment: I'm adding my last comment as an answer as looked quite in place. Sometimes there are user issues related to this.

Comment: @aspirinemaga, glad to hear that worked for you - I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current cron is set up to run a PHP which then invokes another PHP script. You could greatly simplify this by invoking that command in crontab instead:

```
0 8,12,14,16,19,23 * * * php /var/www/domain.com/artisan domaincom:cron argument1 argument2 --option1
```

As others have stated in the comments, it might be helpful for troubleshooting to send the output to a file. This can be done by adding `>> ~/output.txt` to the end of the command to store the output in the home directory in a file named `output.txt` (You can of course, pick any other path).

Answer (score 1):

You should check your user has access to execute cron jobs. When you login to your VPS you login with a specific user (unless you do it with root access).

So you can check at /etc/cron.allow and see if your user is listed there. If it is not you can add your username there in a line. Also check /etc/cron.deny to see if your username is listed, or if ALL is listed there. If ALL is listed there it means you definitely need to add your username to /etc/cron.allow